# object match , increase and add to list

Tags: java, java-8

I have a type of object which contains id and points information.

I have a list of that object. I need to add each new id, if any old id enters i need to add 1 to the points to the old entry .then add to the list.

Here is my pojo

```
public class Salary {

    int id;
    int points;

    public Salary(int id, int points) {
        this.id = id;
        this.points = points;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Here is the situation

```
 class info{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Salary> salaries = new ArrayList<>();
        salaries.add(new Salary(1,100));
        salaries.add(new Salary(2,200));

        Salary newSalary = new Salary(1,200);
    }
}
```

Since the id is same i need to make 100 to 101 and update the list , how can i do that with java 8 ?

Comment: Why not use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`?

Comment: `101` or `300` (100 + 200)?

Comment: Why does it increment to 101 when the new salary is 200?

Comment: 101 , it has to be 101

Comment: That is the point only , if old id enters i need to increase it

Comment: @TheProfiler so, you are simply incrementing last value ?

Comment: you should clarify why does `100` go to `101`?

Comment: if the id alreday exists i need to increment the existing value

Comment: @holi-java he more interesting part is what if that list has `Salary(1, 100)` and `Salary(1, 200)` and you are looking at `Salary(1, 300)`. what should happen?

Comment: it seems to `Map#merge` feature, you can use `Map<Integer, Saraly>`

Comment: OK but how can i increment the value if id matches, becaue the value is an object

Comment: override equals and hashcode and check if(salaries.contains(newSalary ))....

Comment: @Eugene I just need to increase the 1st value with 1 if same id enters

Comment: this would be sooo much easier with a simple loop

Comment: can you please help me out :(

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do. Do you already have a list of salaries and you are receiving one new instance of salary and you need to add 1 to the points attribute of the salary in your list that has the same id of the new instance? Or do you have to reduce your list?

Comment: I have to add +1 to the points if ID matches , if ID does not match, complete object will be added to the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Salary class you should implement equals and hashcode as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Salary other = (Salary) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

and in your main method add this:

```
Salary newSalary = new Salary(1,200);

for(Salary s: salaries){
    if(s.equals(newSalary)){
        s.points++;
      }
  }
```

Comment: It depends how you implement the overridden methods. In the answer that I posted it only looks at the id.

Comment: what should happen in your program when the id and poinst of newSalary are the same of an existing one?

Comment: exact same , then `for(Salary s: salaries){
            if(s.equals(newSalary.getId())){
                s.points++;
                System.out.println(s.getPoints());
            }
            System.out.println(s.getPoints());

        }`

Comment: didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: for that case the old point will be incremented as well , newSalary points does not have any impeact, the old entry will only increment if the id is same

Comment: It does not work , ihave pasted your code to the POJO and then applied the loop in the main

Comment: what is not working? I have tested it from my side. when I do this  for(Salary s:salaries){
         System.out.println(s.id + " " + s.points);
        } it prints  " 1 101  -   2 200 ". Is that what you want?

Comment: and that's exactly what is happening when I am testing it. Make sure your code is the same as mine. The overridden methods and the loop.

Comment: When I read “you should implement equals and hashcode”, I expected code utilizing these methods (e.g. via `HashMap`) to follow, but then, there’s a plain linear search, just using `if(s.equals(newSalary))` instead of `if(s.id == newSalary.id)`…seriously? Implement these two methods for *that*?

Comment: @Holger , you are right, but I wanted to introduce this concept to the OP.